# Unable to check for space, new line and delimiter from text file - python

Tags: python

Text File has multiple lines such as below:

```
01      19-07-2000      09:30:40        'fe2962545516         5001
01      19-07-2000      09:30:40        'fe2962545516         5001
01      19-07-2000      09:30:40        'fe2962545516         5001
01      19-07-2000      09:30:40        'fe2962545516         5001
```

my code:

```
ReadFile = open(file,'r')
read = ReadFile.read()
print(read.strip())
```

The problem is that python doesn't read the space between all values and doesn't read the new line for the next line.  If I put it in a list

```
res=[]
read.append(res)
print(res)
```

It's inserted as res[0] & not res[1..x].

What I want to do is read the text file and create a new file with the columns 2,3 & 4. I have 100s of auto generated files which I want to read so copy/past the values in another text file is not an viable alternative.

Comment: Did you mean `res.append(read)`? You should look at the csv module.

Comment: It read and inserted as res[0] & not as res[1..x] .  Its written in the Q

Comment: Strings have no `append` method, `read.append` is an error. Your Q has non-working code.

Answer (score 0):

Read the file and append it to an array:

```
with open(file) as f:
    res = f.readlines()
res = [x.strip() for x in res]
```

Print the array line by line:

```
for i in res:
    print i
```

Print the line 2:

```
print res[2]
```

Comment: Thats the problem, it comes as a single item and does not read a new line

Comment: You started your question with `Text File has multiple lines`. So?

Comment: The OP has `ReadFile.read()` - reads the whole file as one string. This answer has `f.readlines()` which creates a list of the lines.

Comment: Yes, Please check, I also wrote "The problem is that python doesn't read the space between all values and doesn't read the new line for the next line."

Comment: OP, yes we can all read what you wrote. Doesn't mean we understand any of it!

Comment: OP, you need to amend your question to provide the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a file and convert it to another with just the middle columns present you can do this:

```
with open(ifile) as f:
    res = f.readlines()  # Read whole file as lines

res = [x.strip() for x in res] # Remove line feeds

res = [' '.join(x.split()[1:-1]) for x in res] # Remove first and last columns

with open(ofile,'w') as f:
    f.write("\n".join(res))  # Write to a different file with line feeds
```